# Lightdm won't start after installing CUDA 7 drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, lightdm, cuda

I recently installed CUDA 7 on ubuntu using a downloaded .run file. After the installation, I found that not only was lightdm not starting, I also couldn't start lightdm using`sudo start lightdm`. (Trying returned `start: Job failed to start`). I have tried switching to gdm, yet it results in a black screen as well. I also tried reinstalling lightdm, reconfiguring it, and making sure that it was my default display manager.Currently, the only way I have access to the computer is using SSH. This is the third time that I have ran into this problem and therefore my third installation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See [this related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/759641/cant-get-nvidia-drivers-working-with-16-04-logs-out-right-after-login?noredirect=1&lq=1) and others.