# Can't get nVidia drivers working with 16.04, logs out right after login

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, lightdm

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 beta 2 on Monday, Apr 18th. When I try to install nvidia-current, nvidia-361 or the version that jockey installs, either lightdm fails to start entirely or I can't get past the login window. When I log in, lightdm.log reports that I have logged in successfully, for some reasons it shows the sound volume I have set and then it returns back to the login screen.

I have a laptop with hybrid nVidia/Intel graphics with the Optimus technology (I don't really need GPU switching, but I want nVidia to run properly), the exact nVidia model is GT630M.

Here is Xorg.0.log:

```
[    41.529] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.3
Release Date: 2016-04-04
[    41.529] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    41.529] Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-85-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    41.529] Current Operating System: Linux dugi 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64
[    41.529] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic root=UUID=77b76089-cd8b-4d0c-b074-1ec581c0a8a9 ro quiet splash
[    41.529] Build Date: 07 April 2016  09:18:50AM
[    41.529] xorg-server 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    41.529] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[    41.529]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    41.529] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    41.529] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Apr 22 00:40:13 2016
[    41.530] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    41.530] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    41.530] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    41.530] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    41.530] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    41.530] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    41.530] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    41.530] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    41.530] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    41.530] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    41.530] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    41.530]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    41.530] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    41.530]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    41.530] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    41.530]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    41.530] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    41.530]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    41.530] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    41.530]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    41.530] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    41.530] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    41.530] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    41.530] (II) Loader magic: 0x55a83676cda0
[    41.530] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    41.530]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    41.530]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    41.530]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    41.530]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    41.530] (++) using VT number 7

[    41.530] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    41.531] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    41.532] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0166:1028:0590 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf7400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[    41.532] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    41.532] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    41.532] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    41.532] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    41.537] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    41.537]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    41.537]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    41.537] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.131  Sun Nov  8 22:03:20 PST 2015
[    41.537] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    41.537] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[    41.537] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    41.537] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    41.537] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    41.537] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    41.537] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    41.537] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    41.537] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    41.537]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.99.917
[    41.537]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    41.537]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    41.537] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    41.537] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    41.537] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    41.537]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.18.3
[    41.537]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    41.537]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    41.537] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    41.538] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    41.538] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    41.538]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    41.538]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    41.538]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    41.538] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    41.538] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    41.538] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    41.538]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    41.538]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    41.538]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    41.538] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    41.538] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[    41.538] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[    41.538] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[    41.538] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    41.538] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    41.538] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    41.538] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20151010
[    41.538] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[    41.538] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[    41.538] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    41.538] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    41.538] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    41.538] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    41.538] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    41.538] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    41.538]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    41.538]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    41.538] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    41.539] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
[    41.539] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx; using a maximum of 2 threads
[    41.539] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    41.539] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    41.539] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    41.539] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    41.539] (II) intel(0): Output LVDS1 has no monitor section
[    41.552] (--) intel(0): Found backlight control interface intel_backlight (type 'raw') for output LVDS1
[    41.552] (II) intel(0): Enabled output LVDS1
[    41.552] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[    41.552] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VGA1
[    41.552] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[    41.552] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[    41.552] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[    41.552] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
[    41.552] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[    41.552] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[    41.552] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[    41.552] (--) intel(0): Output LVDS1 using initial mode 1366x768 on pipe 0
[    41.552] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[    41.552] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    41.552] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    41.552] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    41.552] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    41.552] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[    41.552] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[    41.552] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[    41.552] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    41.552] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    41.552] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    41.552] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    41.553] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    41.553] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    41.553] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    41.553] (II) Unloading vesa
[    41.553] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    41.553] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Ivybridge (gen7, gt2) backend
[    41.553] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[    41.553] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    41.553] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[    41.553] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    41.553] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[    41.553] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[    41.553] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    41.553] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[    41.553] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[    41.553] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[    41.553] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[    41.553] (--) RandR disabled
[    41.556] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    41.557] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
[    41.558] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[    41.558] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 361 x 203
[    41.582] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[    41.582] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    41.582] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    41.582] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    41.582] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    41.582]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.10.1
[    41.582]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    41.582]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[    41.582] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    41.582] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    41.582] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    41.582] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    41.583] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    41.583] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    41.583] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3/event3"
[    41.583] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    41.583] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    41.583] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    41.583] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "sk"
[    41.583] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "qwerty"
[    41.596] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event6)
[    41.596] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    41.596] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[    41.596] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    41.596] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[    41.596] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[    41.596] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[    41.596] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[    41.596] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input8/event6"
[    41.596] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    41.596] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    41.596] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    41.596] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "sk"
[    41.596] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "qwerty"
[    41.596] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event5)
[    41.596] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    41.596] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[    41.596] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    41.596] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[    41.596] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[    41.596] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[    41.596] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[    41.596] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:19/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7/event5"
[    41.596] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    41.596] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    41.596] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    41.596] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "sk"
[    41.596] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "qwerty"
[    41.597] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    41.597] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    41.597] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    41.597] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    41.597] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    41.597] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    41.597] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    41.597] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    41.597] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[    41.597] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    41.597] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    41.597] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    41.597] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "sk"
[    41.597] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "qwerty"
[    41.597] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[    41.597] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    41.597] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    41.598] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    41.598] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    41.598] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Sleep Button'
[    41.598] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[    41.598] (**) evdev: Sleep Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    41.598] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x3
[    41.598] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Found keys
[    41.598] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    41.598] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2/event2"
[    41.598] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    41.598] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    41.598] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    41.598] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "sk"
[    41.598] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "qwerty"
[    41.598] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 04d9:1133 (/dev/input/event7)
[    41.598] (**) HID 04d9:1133: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    41.598] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HID 04d9:1133'
[    41.598] (**) HID 04d9:1133: always reports core events
[    41.598] (**) evdev: HID 04d9:1133: Device: "/dev/input/event7"
[    41.652] (--) evdev: HID 04d9:1133: Vendor 0x4d9 Product 0x1133
[    41.652] (--) evdev: HID 04d9:1133: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    41.652] (--) evdev: HID 04d9:1133: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    41.652] (--) evdev: HID 04d9:1133: Found relative axes
[    41.652] (--) evdev: HID 04d9:1133: Found x and y relative axes
[    41.652] (II) evdev: HID 04d9:1133: Configuring as mouse
[    41.652] (II) evdev: HID 04d9:1133: Adding scrollwheel support
[    41.652] (**) evdev: HID 04d9:1133: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    41.652] (**) evdev: HID 04d9:1133: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    41.652] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:04D9:1133.0001/input/input9/event7"
[    41.652] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID 04d9:1133" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[    41.652] (II) evdev: HID 04d9:1133: initialized for relative axes.
[    41.652] (**) HID 04d9:1133: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    41.652] (**) HID 04d9:1133: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    41.652] (**) HID 04d9:1133: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    41.652] (**) HID 04d9:1133: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    41.653] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 04d9:1133 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    41.653] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    41.653] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    41.653] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD (/dev/input/event10)
[    41.653] (**) Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    41.653] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD'
[    41.653] (**) Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD: always reports core events
[    41.653] (**) evdev: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD: Device: "/dev/input/event10"
[    41.653] (--) evdev: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD: Vendor 0x1bcf Product 0x2982
[    41.653] (--) evdev: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD: Found keys
[    41.653] (II) evdev: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD: Configuring as keyboard
[    41.653] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/input/input12/event10"
[    41.653] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[    41.653] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    41.653] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    41.653] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "sk"
[    41.653] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "qwerty"
[    41.653] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event12)
[    41.653] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    41.653] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    41.654] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event13)
[    41.654] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    41.654] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    41.654] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event14)
[    41.654] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    41.654] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    41.654] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer (/dev/input/event9)
[    41.654] (**) Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: Applying InputClass "evdev touchscreen catchall"
[    41.654] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer'
[    41.654] (**) Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: always reports core events
[    41.654] (**) evdev: Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: Device: "/dev/input/event9"
[    41.709] (--) evdev: Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: Vendor 0x3eb Product 0x8803
[    41.709] (--) evdev: Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: Found absolute axes
[    41.709] (--) evdev: Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: Found absolute multitouch axes
[    41.709] (II) evdev: Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: No buttons found, faking one.
[    41.709] (--) evdev: Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: Found x and y absolute axes
[    41.709] (--) evdev: Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: Found absolute touchscreen
[    41.709] (II) evdev: Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: Configuring as touchscreen
[    41.709] (**) evdev: Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    41.709] (**) evdev: Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    41.709] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/0003:03EB:8803.0002/input/input10/event9"
[    41.709] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 13)
[    41.709] (II) evdev: Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: initialized for absolute axes.
[    41.709] (**) Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    41.709] (**) Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    41.709] (**) Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    41.709] (**) Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    41.710] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer (/dev/input/mouse2)
[    41.710] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    41.710] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    41.710] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[    41.710] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    41.710] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    41.710] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[    41.710] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[    41.710] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[    41.710] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[    41.710] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    41.710] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/event4"
[    41.710] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[    41.710] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    41.710] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    41.710] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "sk"
[    41.710] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "qwerty"
[    41.710] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event8)
###/// A load of unrelated stuff about touchpad ///###
[    41.794] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input13/event11"
[    41.794] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Dell WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 16)
[    41.794] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    41.794] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    41.794] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "sk"
[    41.794] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "qwerty"
[    42.345] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5558
[    42.345] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    42.345] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.66  1366 1397 1462 1592  768 772 784 802 +hsync -vsync (48.2 kHz eP)
[    42.345] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   51.01  1366 1380 1409 1592  768 770 777 800 +hsync -vsync (32.0 kHz e)
```

This is the xorg.conf.XXXXXXXX in use:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:2@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

For now, I am stuck with nouveau/intel, which is sometimes quite limiting. Any idea what can be going on? Maybe the missing /etc/X11/xorg.conf file could be the problem, but I don't know why it isn't there.

Note:
As of the main release of 16.04, the error has changed from *no devices detected* and *no screens found* to *Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)*. Now, lightdm starts easier, but I still can't get past the login screen.

Further edit:
I had secure boot disabled all the time. I have installed bumblebee that added the nvidia driver (tried 304 and 340), but it was not able to start programs using the nVidia video card. Futher investigation has shown that modprobe for nvidia was failing due to something like this:

```
could not insert 'nvidia': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

I tried a later version of the driver (361), but it kept on failing. I have read somewhere that i915 drivers were causing this trouble, but I had not them installed.

More information:
This appears to be the root cause. With nVidia driver installed together with its DKMS module, I could not insert it into kernel (using modprobe). The reported error was that it can't find it a specific PCI port (the one where it should be according to lspci). I haven't saved the exact wording, sorry for that.

Comment: I had the same problem until I installed nvidia-364 from the nvidia graphics driver ppa. However, the login bug reappeared when I installed prime-indicator, so I had to remove that again. But nvidia-364 and disabled secure boot works for me. I have an Nvidia 940M card.

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: It works! Installing nvidia-364 and rebooting fixed the issue. I had to delete ~/.config/dconf/user to get to Unity.

Comment: I have a similar issue - I think. Can you add to your question which display adapter are you actually using for X? Is it the Intel or the NVIDIA?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to the collective effort of the community, I have managed to get it working.

First, get to a Terminal (by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f1</kbd> if you can't log in, or through recovery mode). Install nVidia drivers version 364 (package nvidia-364).

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
```

If the package is not found, add the ppa that contains it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Reboot your computer.

```
sudo reboot -i NOW
```

If you're not thrown back to the login screen, but you get to see only your background, force it to recreate your user settings (saving a backup):

```
sudo mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old
```

Then, restart lightdm:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

If you want to install bumblebee, beware that its configuration will be set badly and it will look for nvidia-current even if nvidia-current is not installed. I have edited it to refer to nvidia-364 instead (because the installed files are in /usr/lib/nvidia-364) and I was able to start programs with optirun.

Comment: My situation is pretty similar to yours, but the drivers from the PPA thingy are even worse than the ones from nvidia.com, on my machine:  Instead of the login loop the .run version gives me, I get a black screen.  You got lucky, I guess.  Such is Linux:  Some shall fail, while others succeed, and neither will ever understand why.

Comment: Have you tried the other options mentioned in this thread or a combination thereof?

Comment: Yeah.  I've tried many things mentioned in many threads.  I eventually gave up and decided to reinstall Linux altogether, and a different distribution of it too, just to increase the chance of a beneficial shakeup.  If that in turn fails then I will probably buy a new video card, ideally one without that filthy Optimus nonsense.

Comment: Why v364 rather than any other version?

Comment: It didn't work on earlier versions, v367 wasn't out back then and I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Same as J Quigley, I got the black screen. However, this approach saves me:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/878117/-solved-titan-x-for-cuda-7-5-login-loop-error-ubuntu-14-04-/
Basically, when you install Nvidia driver by .run file, don't install opengl file. For example
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run --no-opengl-files
Hopefully it works for you too.

Comment: I was able to install nvidia-384 using this method.  nvidia-364 is no longer in the repo.  This fixed my log in issues.

Answer (score 7):

I had some problems with Nvidia and 16.04 - finally got it working. on an nvidia gtx980m (asus G752 gaming laptop) - I suggest making sure you try to install from command line, and not simply enabling the proprietary drivers from the gui...(read on)

I am not getting the boot loop described, but I was getting low res (800x600) and it would not work at all - but the nouveau one was fine. (all via the drivers gui)

I finally dropped to command line and installed the same package via "sudo apt-get install nvidia-xxx (in my case was 361 - also tried 352)

it then installed as normal, but a menu popped in the terminal up that said "UEFI" secure boot was enabled and you would have to put in a one time password to disable it on reboot" to boot into insecure mode. So I did that.

Once that was done, on reboot - sure enough a UEFI window menu popped up and I choosed to change boot mode to insecure. It then asked me several characters "by position" (EG...type in character 6, then type in character 4, etc) followed by enter each time. Eventually after 3-4 characters, it allowed me to turn off secure boot. Then the machine rebooted again, and said "booting insecure mode" and the drivers then worked.

Also discovered then when installing virtualbox as well via synaptic, but at least it worked and popped up a menu using that method....

hope that helps...

Comment: I have the secure boot disabled, I had difficulties even with installing Linux without it.

Comment: You can reboot and disable secure boot from BIOS settings without any stupid passwords.

Comment: Secure boot just cost me 1 hour. Thank you very much for the tip!

Comment: Disabling the secure boot from BIOS and enabling legacy boot fixed the login-problem for me on HP Desktop PC.

Answer (score 5):

## How do I get my desktop back?

By pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f1</kbd> from the login screen, you can go to a commandline. Login using your username and password. From this commandline, you can uninstall the nvidia drivers by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove nvidia-361
sudo apt autoremove
```

*Note that the specific version of nvidia might be different. You can find out the version of the installed nvidia driver by running `apt search nvidia | grep installed | grep nvidia`*

**or** if you just want to switch to the Intel graphics card without removing the nvidia driver, run

```
prime-select intel
```

## But I want to use my nvidia card!

There are a few options you can try:

### Disable secure boot

As @biff said, Secure Boot might block the nvidia driver from loading. To disable secure boot, install the nvidia driver **using the commandline**. Ubuntu will ask you to disable secure boot during the installation.

### Install the older nvidia driver

Some problems might be fixed by installing the older nvidia driver.

Comment: I don't know how old nVidia drivers you mean, because nvidia-304 didn't work neither.

Comment: Secure boot handling in Ubuntu is intolerable.

Comment: I had to install Nvidia libraries for development but do not have an Nvidia card. I then installed Intel OpenCL drivers (with the kernel patch), which forced the reboot and resulted in the login loop. This solution with "prime-select intel" resolves this particular (strange) issue. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed the login loop problem when running under VirtualBox by using the `prime-select intel` command from a console (Ctrl-Alt-F1), then restarting the VM (If don't restart the VM, gui starts but udev continually tries to restart nvidia-persistenced.service). I use the same partition when booting Ubuntu 16.04 natively and using the VirtualBox raw partition functionality. I needed the proprietary nVidia drivers (nvidia-384), when booted natively, to get a high resolution, but when using VirtualBox, the login loop occurred (syslog: NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adaptor found!).

Comment: ... After rebooting native, `prime-select query` shows prime has automatically gone back to 'nvidia' and all is OK. It's a pain I have to set mode back to intel every time I want VB after native but I can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a GTX980 and was not able to login after upgrade to 16.04 (from 15.10). Remove nvidia:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

and logged in. It worked but resolution was limited to 800x600.

Following steps resolved my issue:

1. Reinstall nvidia: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-361`
2. Reboot, goto BIOS and disable Secure Boot

Thanks biff for the tip to disable secure boot :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Running Ubuntu 16.04. Intel HD4600 and Nvidia 765M. Tried all the suggestions above. 
It worked when installing using terminal, but if I use multiple monitors it bugs out and I end up in a boot loop.

I've read someone suggesting that the beta driver 364xx works.

Comment: Windows works, that's for sure.  :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just installing nvidia-364 solved the problem.  My configuration is NVidia GTX 750Ti on ASUS H170 + Intel i7 6700 + 32Gb DDR4 running Ubuntu 16.04.