# 16.04 Nvidia proprietary driver problems

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, encryption, 16.04

On 16.04 xubuntu fresh install, I have an Nvidia Gtx 980 and an apple 30" 2560x1600 display, after installing proprietary nvidia drivers, I get two problems, the first, I can't log in during the encryption screen, the screen resolution is very low, and I can't type in my password. I've been having a hard time troubleshooting this, is the part where you input your password to unlock your encrypted drive called the boot splash screen, or something else?

When I have the open source noveau drivers, the encryption login screen is at a much higher resolution and I can type my password in. The only way I can log in is with recovery mode for now, which leads me to the next problem.

The second problem, with the proprietary nvidia drivers, it does not recognize my monitor as of 16.04, and it does not show up at all in the monitor panel in ubuntu, and it only gives me one resolution option to choose from, which is a very low resolution.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: so 'disabling' secure boot has fixed the second problem, unfortunately, I still get the first problem. The only way to boot into my pc is to boot it once, turn it off as I can't do anything at the encryption screen, and it's still low resolution only at the encryption log in screen, boot it a second time, then it loads grub, I continue a normal boot, I get a black screen instead of the Luks password screen, I type in my encryption password, and I can log in.

In my bios of my asus z170-a motherboard I had to pick "other os" under secure boot, but it still says secure boot is enabled, I read that I have to delete the secure boot keys to disable secure boot completely. Does secure boot add any security benefits to Linux? Can I disable secure boot from Ubuntu if I can't from my bios?

Comment: Encryption password problem is the same for me on Kubuntu 15.10 -> 16.04. Just upgraded today and I'm already regretting it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get nVidia drivers working with 16.04, logs out right after login](http://askubuntu.com/questions/759641/cant-get-nvidia-drivers-working-with-16-04-logs-out-right-after-login)

Comment: All these symptoms hint to the nvidia driver not being loaded correctly. This might be caused by secure boot, see the possible duplicate for a solution.

Comment: I have an issue with nvidia drivers and a GTX 770 card, after 16.04 LTS install, where attempting to run OpenGL-based programs causes the `libGLX.nvidia.so` library to segfault internally, so the programs that used to run fine, do not run anymore. I sent a bug report to `linux-bugs@nvidia.com`. They responded by saying: "Tracking this issue internally as bug 200194572".