# Xorg blank screen - after installing nVIDIA drivers v361/v367 (and card not used for display)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, xorg, cuda

I have a problem which is similar, but may not the same, as in several other questions asked here. The closest seems to be:

[Can't get nVidia drivers working with 16.04, logs out right after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759641/cant-get-nvidia-drivers-working-with-16-04-logs-out-right-after-login)

Here's my scenario:

- Kubuntu 16.04 64-bit, freshly installed.
- Desktop machine with an on-board (on-chip) Intel display, and a discrete nVIDIA GTX 650 Ti - not used for display, just for computation.
- Installing nVIDIA driver version either 361.62 or 367.35 (both with same result)
- No 'Optimus', whatever that is.

Well, the driver installation works (but it begins with a complaint about a preinstall script failing); and on reboot, the nVIDIA driver(s) appears with lsmod. Also, CUDA code runs successfully so no problem there.

However... when booting the VT in which X is supposed to show me a login screen is blank. The machine doesn't hang (I can work on other VTs), nor does X crash. The errors I get in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` are:

```
[    15.618] (EE) NOUVEAU(G0): [XvMC] Failed to initialize extension.
[    15.642] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

If I uninstall the nVIDIA driver, X works properly again (will quote some log messages here soon).

The solution for the similar question does *not* work for me. So my question is:

How can I have the nVIDIA drivers installed and the X server work, considering the fact that I do *not* use the nVIDIA card for display at all?

Obviously, a solution which prevents X from "noticing" the nVIDIA card would work well for me.

FYI - I'm also having a variant of this problem on Debian Stretch, so a non-Ubuntu-specific solution would be swell if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem is *not* really, or note entirely, with the X server - which does load. It's the display manager I was using by default - SDDM; or perhaps some functionality it tries to use, and fails. If I switch to LXDM as the display manager and LXDE as the desktop environment, that works.

So - not quite a solution, but a workaround.